# How to use a (toLowerCase()) similar method in angular html file?

Tags: angular

I'm using observables to get each letter from an input type text in the same moment and show child component based on conditions (the restaurant name should include same letters entered in the text input).
I can't figure a way to do it in the ts file , but it works absolutely fine on this code:

```
  <div *ngFor="let res of restaurants">
    <li
      *ngIf="(res.Name.includes(searchString) || searchLength == false) &&(res.Address == printedOption || checked == false)"
      class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
      <a class="nav-link active">
        <app-res-tabs [res]="res"></app-res-tabs>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
```

the problem is that I need it to be not case sensitive.
(Above code works fine for `Xres` and `Xres` ,  but doesn't for `xres` and `Xres` for example).
How to make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
*ngIf="(res.Name?.toLowerCase().includes(searchString?.toLowerCase()) || searchLength == false)
```

Comment: I tried it already.
it gives an error: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined and nothing shows at first (all restaurant should be shown by default at first)

Comment: Add safe navigation operator `?`. Check the modified answer

Comment: You are welcome. Accept the answer if it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Angular [tolowercase](https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe) Pipe

`*ngIf="((res.Name|lowercase).includes(searchString|lowercase) || searchLength == false) &&(res.Address == printedOption || checked == false)"`